# Flexbox with fixed width child ignoring width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a 3 column layout where I can collapse the 3rd column. My idea was to simply set the length to a fixed number for the child (e.g. 600px or 100px for collapsed) and this doesn't seem to work. Any hints on what I may be doing wrong?

```css
.container { 
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left { 
  flex-basis: 2rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.main {
  flex: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.right {
  flex-basis: 600px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.child {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi:) What do you mean by 'I can collapse the 3rd column'? How?

Comment: I'll add some code logic that changes the width of #child from 600px to 100px and vica verca

Comment: What do like to happen when the 3rd column collapses? The middle column to expand?

Comment: Exactly, that was my thought with flex-grow 1 on middle column

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to .right element?

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussion above you simply have to remove 'flex-basis: 600px;' from .right rule:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .left {
      flex-basis: 2rem;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
      padding: 2rem;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .main {
      flex: auto;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
      padding: 2rem;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .right {
      /*flex-basis: 600px;*/
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-grow: 0;
      overflow-x: auto;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    
    .child {
      width: 600px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if this is not the desired effect.

Comment: It does not help, as it does not take away 600px of width, the child is actually outside of the screen.

Comment: If you check the answer on a smaller screen, the right div width is not 600px.

Comment: yeah! and so when you change it to 100px the .main widens.  Or do you want to change .right to 100px automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a simple way. Just set the left column and vary with the main and the right ones.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let main = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
let right = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];
    
const shrinkRightColumn = () => {
        right.style.width = 5 + '%';
        main.style.width = 85 + '%';    
}
    
button.addEventListener("click", shrinkRightColumn);
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;      
}
.left{
    background: red;
    width: 10%; 
}
.main{
    background: green;  
    width: 70%;
}
.right{
    background: yellow; 
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">a</div>
    <div class="main">a</div>
    <div class="right">a</div>
 </div>  


<button id="button" type="button">Shrink</button>
```